# Could not resolve project :reactnativenotifications

Tags: android, react-native, notifications

While adding react-native-notifications package using `npm i react-native-notifications` and setting all the required steps for the android platform, still getting:

> Could not resolve project :reactnativenotifications

Answer (score 3):

Please add the missing part in the android's build.gradle file under "android/app/build.gradle' as per the docs: [1]

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.packagename.app"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion  
 +  missingDimensionStrategy "RNNotifications.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative60" // See note below!
    -
    -
  }
```

Use `"reactNative60"` for 0.60.x and above and `"reactNative59"` for 0.59.x and below.